# is there any distance measuring sensor in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo-tutorial

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I m beginner in gazebo and robotics .is there any sensor in gazebo by which i find the distance of object ,i used Hokuyo laser range finders which is given in  tutorial http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/control_robot/mobile_base_laser .as far i understood it send a broad laser so it detect any object in that area(circumference ) ,but how can i know in which direction obstacle is present and how can i navigate my robot to avoid obstacle .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4041/is-there-any-distance-measuring-sensor-in-gazebo-?/) by [suvrat](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/438/suvrat/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 53 on 2013-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you take a look into the [hokuyo model's SDF](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/6cd587c0a30e/hokuyo/model.sdf?at=default) you can see, that the laser takes 640 samples (`<samples>640</samples>`). With the resolution (`<resolution>1</resolution>`)  and the min angle and max angle (`<min_angle>-2.26889</min_angle>`, `<max_angle>2.268899</max_angle>`) you have everything you need.

Then for example in a plugin go through the samples ([for this you should take a look in the control model tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/intermediate/control_model)) and check the distances:
If sample 0 detects a low range then you know, that from your sensor direction in the angle of -2.26889 there is an object.

Edit: perhaps its easier to connect a simple ray sensor to your mobile robot. Then you can control things like angle and samples without editing the hokuyo model.

---

Originally posted by [Chris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/269/chris/) with karma: 67 on 2013-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [suvrat](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/438/suvrat/) on 2013-08-02**:
thanks @chris i will try this .thank you very much for help.

**Comment by [Chris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/269/chris/) on 2013-08-02**:
No problem. If you have further questions, let me know

**Comment by [suvrat](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/438/suvrat/) on 2013-08-03**:
thanks a lot @chris ,i solved my problem

**Comment by [anonymous](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/957/anonymous/) on 2014-11-21**:
Hey. I am also doing the same work of obstacle avoidance but when i did it with polaris_ranger_model this control model tutorial is not working . Polaris dont stop. Can you plz suggest how will i do it with polaris ranger model so that it should stop when it detects the object. Thanks!